# react-input-range does not trigger events(onChange, onClick) inside react-leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-component

I have here some interesting case! 
I'm using a [react-input-range](https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range) inside a [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) Marker Popup

Which is something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map as LeafletMap, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import InputRange from 'react-input-range';

export default class MapPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: { min: 2, max: 200 },
      name: 'sample name',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*
          * This input range outside LeafletMap works
        */}
        <InputRange
          maxValue={300}
          minValue={0}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
        />
        <LeafletMap center={[0, 0]} zoom={16}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={[0, 0]}>
            <Popup>
              {/*
                * This input below works
              */}
              <input
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={({ target }) => this.setState({ name: target.value })}
              />
              {/*
                * This input range INSIDE LeafletMap does not work
              */}
              <InputRange
                maxValue={300}
                minValue={0}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
              />
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </LeafletMap>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I know so far

- The `input range` component works outside the `LeafletMap` component.
- Native input works inside the `LeafletMap` component!
- I've confirmed that a native input works inside the popup! The `input range` works on mobile(android chrome browser)! (swipe & click events)

**Any ideas how to make input range work inside react-leaflet map**?

Here's a few more details that might help:

- react-leaflet: ^2.0.0-rc.3
- react: 16.4.2
- react-input-range: ^1.3.0

**Testing Env**

Browsers: Chrome 64.0.32, Firefox 61 and Safari 11.1

OS: Mac OSX High Sierra 10.13.5

Codepen: https://codepen.io/codepen-theo/pen/OwdLXY?editors=0010

Comment: Are there any console errors? Also, have you tried debugging the props with this tool at all? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Comment: no errors mate, and events weren't triggered at all. I am using https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate w/ https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger since the react-dev tools did not play well with the boilerplate @dkniffin

Comment: Does it work with multiple InputRange at all? This library seems to have do some very confusing stuff to attach and destroy event listeners on the document node. I suspect that instances of the components might be messing with the global event listeners from the other InputRange components.

Comment: Hi @HåkenLid, i tried adding 2 input ranges at the same time(outside map), both worked. does this clear some of your assumptions?

Comment: Yes. But I suspect that the problem might be related to how react-input-range handles events. It needs to attach event listeners to the document node, but with leaflet, there's some complicated stuff going on using react portals and iframes. So my guess is that some assumptions made by input range are not true in this case. Can you link to a running example of your code in a codepen or something like that? The specific combination of these two libraries is probabaly not so common.

Comment: That's true! Culprit most likely is how react-input-range manages events since events were triggered for native input elements. let me see if I can come up with some code pen

Comment: @HåkenLid here https://codepen.io/codepen-theo/pen/OwdLXY?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what's happening. But I'm not sure there's a good way to get it to work as you want.

What happens is that leaflet.js will call `event.stopPropagation()` on the mousedown event when it bubbles to the popup element. This blocks reacts synthetic events from working as expected. React's event propagation is handled independently of the native bubbling / capturing.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Popup.js#L185

You can monkey patch the the event listener on the popup wrapper. See this example:

https://codepen.io/haakenlid/pen/ejxNKE

This works by simply removing one of the `preventDefault` event listener that leaflet.js has attached to the plugin wrapper node. (In a very hacky way)

```
class MyPopup extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    if (!this.popup) return
    const el = this.popup.leafletElement
    el._initLayout()
    const wrapper = el._wrapper
    wrapper.removeEventListener('mousedown', wrapper._leaflet_events['mousedown6'])
    console.log('mount')
  }
  render(){
    return <Popup ref={ el=>this.popup = el } {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

This is just a proof of concept. There's a high likelihood that it will break again with future versions of leaflet.js (or in some other way).

Comment: Hey, i'm glad you made it work! i'm confused though, isn't it that the bubble will start from child(input-range-element) to ancestor not the other way around? https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

also, `mousedown` & `onchange` events seems to work with other sibling (native)elements https://codepen.io/codepen-theo/pen/pZGJbg?editors=0010 so i'm a little bit confused why `event.stopPropagation()` on popup wrapper blocks only `input-range` events. 

i see it this way -> http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtjJbVIm4r4iY0IHzWf8?p=preview
Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: React uses its own synthetic events framework and its own bubbling. https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/717/files

Comment: Leaflet only stops propagation on `mousedown`, `touchstart` and `dblclick`. Click events are handled differently. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/dom/DomEvent.js#L185

Comment: alright this makes more sense now. it's quite hassle on my side but i'll consider your early suggestion to try other range pickers since this is making some side effects on the map. great work mate. thanks for all the inputs!